# Facebook authentication, set secret and id via secret manager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, asp.net-core

How to set application id and application secret?

[ImageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBb3R.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using VS 2017, you can right-click on the project in solution and choose "Manage User Secrets".  Keep in mind that these are stored in your user profile on your computer so they do not get committed to a repository.

The empty secrets.json file looks like this:

```
{

}
```

With the Facebook secret, it would look like this:

```
{
  "Authentication:Facebook:AppId": "9872398749827342",
  "Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret": "6d7fs67sdfsdf"
}
```

I'm also assuming you already know how to get the key from the Facebook developer portal.

Now this is only when doing local development.  When you go live in Azure cloud, you'll need to use the Azure Key Vault.